# StateNotifer is providing intial state value (bool) in riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

Hi I am using riverpod to check internet connectivity across the app however the state notifier is giving intial state value only or shoul I saw its value is not changing.
Also yes I am updating state you can see it in the code.

**InternetProvider.dart:**

```
import 'package:internet_connection_checker_plus/internet_connection_checker_plus.dart';
import 'package:riverpod/riverpod.dart';

class ConnectivityStatusNotifier extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  ConnectivityStatusNotifier() : super(false);

  void checkInternet() {
    final listener =
        InternetConnection().onStatusChange.listen((InternetStatus status) {
      if (status == InternetStatus.connected) {
        state = true;
      }
      else{
        state = false;
      }
    });
  }
}

final connectivityProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<ConnectivityStatusNotifier, bool>((ref) {
  return ConnectivityStatusNotifier();
});
```

**In HomeScreen.dart:**

```
final internet = ref.watch(connectivityProvider);

final Widget floatingActionButton = FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        print(internet);
      },
      child: const Icon(Icons.chat),
    );
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZHFN.png)

whether the internet is connected or not its always false

I tried this with connectivity_plus package as well but it also didn't worked.
I have also tried this:[medium.com](https://medium.com/@shreebhagwat94/handle-internet-connectivity-in-flutter-with-riverpod-bbde21c187dc#:%7E:text=Listen%20to%20ConnectivityResult%20changes.&text=First%2C%20we%20create%20two%20nullable,connectivity%20status%20of%20the%20device.) this also didn't worked,this one also provides inital state as well which is connectivitystatus.connected.

Comment: The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: have you issued the appropriate permissions on the platforms?

Comment: yes @Ruble I have added the permission in manifest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all**, when using the [internet_connection_checker_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker_plus) package, you need to give permissions on the platforms:

-> Android

Add the following permissions to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

-> macOS

Add the following permissions to your macOS `.entitlements` files:

```
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

**Then** I rethought your code a bit and wrote another one, more reactive and using `Notifier` instead of the legacy `StateNotifier`:

```dart
final connectivityProvider = NotifierProvider<ConnectivityStatusNotifier, bool>(
  ConnectivityStatusNotifier.new,
);

class ConnectivityStatusNotifier extends Notifier<bool> {
  late InternetConnection _internetConnection;

  @override
  bool build() {
    _internetConnection = InternetConnection();
    final stream = _internetConnection.onStatusChange.listen(_statusListener);

    ref.onDispose(() {
      stream.cancel();
    });

    return false;
  }

  void _statusListener(InternetStatus status) {
    switch (status) {
      case InternetStatus.connected:
        state = true;
      case InternetStatus.disconnected:
        state = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can do something in the interface to just `listen` for changes to the `connectivityProvider`. If desired, you can add an action button to snack:

```dart
class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    ref.listen(connectivityProvider, (_, isConnected) {
      if (!isConnected) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text('No internet connection')),
        );
      }
    });

    return const Text('Next are other widgets');
  }
}
```

It's not very clear **in your code** when you call `checkInternet`. The problem is that if you call it several times without canceling the previous subscription, you will get a small memory leak :) I assume that maybe you forgot to call this function altogether)

Comment: Thankyou @Ruble your code works.I haven't touched riverpod for long time and I didn't knew there were new providers and old one were depricated,Another reason to always check docs :).Also I knew to cancel subscription I just didn't added the dispose method as I was trying to fix the problem first.